# Tcl could not save floating point numbers in binary format

Tags: tcl

I am trying to save a list of numbers in binary format (floating point single)
but Tcl cant save it correctly and I could not gain to correct number when i read the file from vb.net

```
set outfile6 [open "btest2.txt" w+]
fconfigure stdout  -translation binary -encoding binary
set aa {}
set p 0
for {set i 1} {$i <= 1000 } {incr i} {
  lappend aa [expr (1000.0/$i )]
  puts -nonewline $outfile6 [binary format "f" [lindex $aa $p]]
  incr p
}
close $outfile6
```

Comment: Welcome. You seem to miss the brackets around `lindex`, like so: `[lindex $aa $p]`.

Comment: Yes it is corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Tcl cant save it correctly

There are two glitches in your snippet:

- the missing brackets for nested command evaluation around `lindex` (see my comment): `[lindex $aa $p]`
- you `fconfigure`d the `stdout`, rather than your file channel: `fconfigure $outfile6 -translation binary`

With this fixed, the following works for me:

```
set outfile6 [open "btest2.txt" w+]
fconfigure $outfile6 -translation binary
set aa {}
set p 0
for {set i 1} {$i <= 1000 } {incr i} {
  lappend aa [expr (1000.0/$i )]
  puts -nonewline $outfile6 [binary format "f" [lindex $aa $p]]
  incr p
}

close $outfile6
```

### Suggestions for improvement

Your snippet seems overly complicated to me, esp. the loop construct. Simplify to:

- Better use `[scan %f $value]` to explicitly turn a value into the floating point representation, rather than `[expr]`?
- [binary format] takes a counter or wildcard, like `f*`, to process multiple values: `[binary format "f*" $aa]`
- You don't need the loop variables `p`, use `[lindex $aa end]`; or better a loop variable to hold the single added element (rather than to collect it from the list again).
- `-translation binary` implies `-encoding binary`

Comment: It's the other way round: `-translation binary` implies `-encoding binary` and several other options.